# How do you turn a Google Services oAuth2 into a Google Ads API oAuth2 access

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-oauth

So I'm working with Google API Client for PHP and I have an OAuth flow that works,

```
class GoogleClient {
    private static $client_id = "1050479587066-f64vq210hc2m15fdj4r77g8ml7jin30d.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    private static $client_Secret = "CK8orQfPNpD9UgF0bqNJinVI";
    private static $redirect_uri = '/return.php';

    private static $access;

    private static $client = null;

    private static function checkForAccess(){
        if(isset(self::$access)){
            return true;
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['GoogleAuth'])){
            self::$access = $_SESSION['GoogleAuth'];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function GetClient(){
        if(is_null(self::$client)){
            $params = [
                "client_id" => self::$client_id,
                "client_secret" => self::$client_Secret,
                "redirect_uri" => self::$redirect_uri,
                "application_name" => "Test AdWords System"
            ];
            if(self::checkForAccess() && self::isLoggedIn()){
                $param["access_token"] =  self::$access['access_token'];
            }
             //Create and Request to access Google API
            $client = new Google_Client($params);
        }
        return $client;
    }

    public static function doLogin(){
        $scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfp',  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"];
        return self::GetClient()->createAuthUrl($scopes);
    }

    public static function doLoginFinal(){
        if (!$code = $_GET['code']) {
            throw new Exception("Auth Code is missing.");
        }

        $authResponse = self::GetClient()->authenticate($code);
        if (isset($authResponse['error'])) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Unable to get access token.", 
                null, 
                new Exception(
                    "{$authResponse['error']} {$authResponse['error_description']}"
                )
            );
        }

        $_SESSION['GoogleAuth'] = $authResponse;
        self::$access = $authResponse;
    }

    public static function isLoggedIn(){
        if(self::checkForAccess()){
            if(isset(self::$access)){
                $expiresAt = @self::$access['created']+@self::$access['expires_in'];
                return (time() < $expiresAt);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function GetExpiry(){
        if(self::checkForAccess()){
            return self::$access['created']+self::$access['expires_in'];
        }
        throw new Exception("The User is not logged into a google account.");
    }
}
```

now this class is working I'm able to log in and I have the scope for google-adwords the problem comes about due to poor documentation for the [googleads-php-lib](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib)

So from the example to [`getCampaigns`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201806/BasicOperations/GetCampaigns.php) it uses `$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();` but i don't have a file so i went into the [`OAuth2TokenBuilder`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/OAuth2TokenBuilder.php) file I'm unable to work out how i could give the already generated access tokens to the `googleads` objects.

I have double checked the [`google-php-api-client` services repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service) and there is no adwords Service I can use.

I have been digging through the source files of the [`googleads-php-lib`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib) to see if I can find a method to implement this but so far I'm just getting stuck as everything seems to require specific parameter types so I can rig something to provide the details, but the code always seems to rely on multiple classes so I can't just build one that extends a class. and i pass that through.

Keys will be destoried after this test is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after days of digging around source files and hacking this and that I finally found an implementation that works.

After creating my manager account: 
 https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup

So this is the two new methods added to my GoogleClient Static Class

```
private static $developerToken = "";

private static function GetUserRefreshCredentials(){
    return new UserRefreshCredentials(
            null,
            [
                'client_id' => self::$client_id,
                'client_secret' => self::$client_secret,
                'refresh_token' => self::$access['refresh_token']
            ]
        );
}

public function GetAdwordsSession(){
    $builder = new AdWordsSessionBuilder();
    $builder->defaultOptionals();
    $builder->withDeveloperToken(slef::$developerToken);
    return $builder->withOAuth2Credential(self::GetUserRefreshCredentials())->build();
}
```